# Disable "Failed to continue: Check debug console" error message in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

How do I get rid of this annoying message every time there's an error in my code?

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide more details

Comment: @Codemonkey51 I just installed vs code and I'm getting an annoying message every time there's an error in my code. I'm just trying to figure out how to get rid of it, the pop-up is driving me insane.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem:

The error message isn't actually caused by VScode, it's caused by the golang extension.

To disable it you have to go to the extension manager and click the little gear next to the installed extension and revert it to a previous version from the context menu. The version I reverted to is from about a year ago.

If you don't see the little gear icon you need to have the extension installed first.

Answer (score 0):

Add your main.go file path to "program" attribute located in launch.json file.

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "go",
            "request": "launch",
            "mode": "auto",
            "program": "E:/GoProjects/main.go",
            "env": {},
            "args": []
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the Go Lang extension settings and turn off the "Build On Save" feature.